# An adequate difference between $\forall x\in A:P(x)$ and $(\forall x)(x\in A\rightarrow P(x))$?

Tags: predicate-logic, philosophy, first-order-logic, foundations, big-picture

Ever since I was a young student I have felt doubts about the traditional $(\forall x)$-expression: starting a statement with such an irrational lack of focus doesn't seems reasonable! I mean, *all* $x$ $-$ /mind explosion/, is so much that it is absolutely impossible to overview. Here $x$ can be anything: a bacteria that penetrated the cell membrane of some urmetazoan cell and become a part of a process that ended with the creation of the complex mitochondria organelle; a proton that once was a part of a cloud of dust swirled around in a nebulous and now is a part of a neuron in your brain; a sign invented by some being somewhere in space; a class of something; or even a number...

A lot of mathematics is written with the alternative, and logically much more limited, expression $\forall x\in A$, which in my opinion is absolutely unobjectionable. Is it then correct to claim that the mathematical statement $\forall x\in A:P(x)$ is *founded on* the corresponding first order logical statement $(\forall x)(x\in A\rightarrow P(x))$?

Otherwise, I claim, most mathematical theories substantially are founded on propositional logic. Except for the relation $\in$..!

Statements as $(a\in A)$ and $(a\in A\rightarrow P(a))$, where $a$ is a free variable, are substantially structured statements in propositional logic, and with the simple semantic convention:

$(1)\quad(\forall x\in A:P(x))\leftrightarrow(a\in A\rightarrow P(a))$

which induce the complementary rule:

$(2)\quad(\exists x\in A:P(x))\leftrightarrow(\neg\forall x\in A:\neg P(x))\leftrightarrow(a\in A\wedge P(a))$, due to $(1)$.

any mathematical statement can be transformed to such a propositional statement.

**Conjecture**: any structured compound propositional statement can be consistently interpreted as a statement with quantifiers. And different but correct propositional manipulations gives equivalent quantified statements $-$ if all free variables are restricted as members of a given set.

**Note**: all bounded variables must be consequently transformed to free variables and conversely. E.g. when a free variable is transformed into a bounded, all occurrences of that variable must be transformed simultaneously into the same quantifier expression of bounded variables.

**Example**: if $\mathbb N_m=\{x\in\mathbb N|x>m\}$ and $\oplus$ is exclusive or:

$1\oplus(\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+)\oplus(\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+)(m\in\mathbb N)
\oplus(\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+)(m\in\mathbb N)(n\in\mathbb N_m)\oplus$
$(n\in\mathbb N_m)(|x-x_n|<\varepsilon)\leftrightarrow$
$(\varepsilon\notin\mathbb R_+)\oplus(\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+)(m\in\mathbb N)
(1+(n\in\mathbb N_m))\oplus(n\in\mathbb N_m)(|x-x_n|<\varepsilon)\leftrightarrow$
$(\varepsilon\notin\mathbb R_+)\oplus(\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+)(m\in\mathbb N)
(n\notin\mathbb N_m)\oplus(n\in\mathbb N_m)(|x-x_n|<\varepsilon)\leftrightarrow$
$(\varepsilon\notin\mathbb R_+)\vee (m\in\mathbb N\wedge n\notin\mathbb N_m)\vee
(m\in\mathbb N\wedge|x-x_n|<\varepsilon)\leftrightarrow$
$\varepsilon\in\mathbb R_+\rightarrow m\in\mathbb N\wedge(n\in\mathbb N_m\rightarrow |x-x_n|<\varepsilon)\leftrightarrow$
$\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb R_+\exists k\in\mathbb N:n\in\mathbb N_{k}\rightarrow |x-x_n|<\epsilon\leftrightarrow \displaystyle \lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}x_i=x$.

**Question**: are there any adequate reason (except traditional or authority reasons) why the restricted semantic quantifiers in mathematics *must be defined* by the corresponding, much more general, first order logical notation? For example a counter example of the conjecture?

Comment: But this is what you do when consider a model or, more generally, an interpretation of a first order theory with a binary relation. Furthermore $x$ is just a metamathematical variable, while $a$ is internal to the theory.

Comment: That is was logicians do, automatically claim that the logic in mathematics goes back to some definitions in some logical discipline. But it seems that $\forall x\in A$ stand for itself without the need of referring to theoretical logical constructions. It's to simple and objectionable as such.

Comment: Interesting point I am still puzzeling with it, how would you formulate: 
$ \exists x (\lnot Px \land Qx )$ , , 
$ \exists x (\lnot Px \to Qx )$ (almost a tautology. how would you formulate it in your system), ,  
$ \forall x (Px \to \lnot Qx )$ , , 
$ \forall x (Px \equiv \lnot Qx )$ , , ?

Comment: @Willemien: It's only possible to converse limited quantifiers, but if you in the first case mean $\exists x\in X:(\neg Pa\rightarrow Qa)$ then I would write $a\in X\rightarrow(\neg Pa\rightarrow Qa)$ etc.

Comment: @Willemien: correction $\exists x\in X:(\neg Px\rightarrow Qx)$